# Using Calendar while calling

Tags: calendar, calls

Can I access the phone calendar whilst on a call on a Samsung GT i8500.  If so, how?

Comment: Sure, why not? The dialer is just another app. Just pull up the calendar app like you would any other while your call is still active. Is there some reason why that's not working for you?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can.. while the call is active, press the home button. The current call will be minimize on the top notification bar. you can start any other app, while the call is still going on.